# in Next.js 14, styled-components doesn't generate styles on navigation

Tags: next.js, styled-components, vercel, app-router, next.js14

I'm using Next.js 14 with App Router and styled-components, and I've set up my configuration following the guidelines here: https://nextjs.org/docs/architecture/nextjs-compiler#styled-components. However, the components that are supposed to be styled upon the initial client-side render are missing their styles. Refreshing the page fixes the issue, but the styles fail to load during regular navigation!
Also, I'm using SWC as the compiler.

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    typedRoutes: true,
  },
};

module.exports = {
  ...nextConfig,
  reactStrictMode: true,
  transpilePackages: ['ui'],
  swcMinify: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: [{
        loader: '@svgr/webpack',
        options: {
          svgoConfig: {
            plugins: [{
              name: 'preset-default',
              params: {
                overrides: {
                  removeViewBox: false,
                },
              },
            }, ],
          },
        },
      }, ],
    });

    return config;
  },
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
  },
};
```

```js
'use client';
    
import { styled } from 'styled-components';
    
export const Container = styled.div`
    background-color: red;
`;
```

```js
'use client';
    
import * as s from './style';
    
export const Test = () => {
    return <s.Container>Test</s.Container>;
};
```